# How I use prettyPhoto iframe feature in my Angularjs project, I'm succeed in localhost but on serve shows blank page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to use prettyPhoto iframe feature in my Angularjs project which is run in Heroku server. I'm successfully run this feature in my project but it's run locally, when I'm run with **grunt serve:dist** page shows blank and in **inspect element** portion shows many error and this same problem shows on server(when I up my project on heroku server).

In my project when user register successfully with their details and puts his/her website link after that when user goes on their profile and click on their website link the website open up in popup window on same page.

For this fetcher I use tutorial from [this site](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#prettyPhoto)

external sites iframe demo and this example run good on grunt serve but when i run this on grunt serve:dist or on heroku server that show nothing, the page shows blank and in Chrome inspect element shows the problem is in `prettyphoto.js` file

Please gave me solution, why external jquery file not support in my project.
I'm use pretyphoto.js in my index.html file as

```
<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/component.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/iosOverlay.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/progress.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/prettyPhoto.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <!-- endbuild -->
```

I also included two js file in index.html page as:

```
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery-video-lightning.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/iosOverlay.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/pace.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/custom.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-scroll/0.6.5/angular-scroll.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-scroll/0.6.5/angular-scroll.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>        
        <script src="scripts/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

and the html code, small css and small script use in my html page where I use this fetcher

css code for iframe

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
  * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

  body {
    background: #282828;
    font: 62.5%/1.2 Arial, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }

  h1 { font-family: Georgia; font-style: italic; margin-bottom: 10px; }

  h2 {
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 25px 0 5px 0;
  }

  p { font-size: 1.2em; }

  ul li { display: inline; }

  .wide {
    border-bottom: 1px #000 solid;
    width: 4000px;
  }

  .fleft { float: left; margin: 0 20px 0 0; }

  .cboth { clear: both; }

  #main {

    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 1000px;
  }
</style>
```

know the html and script code for the iframe is

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="gallery clearfix"  id="main">
        <li>
      <h4 id="web"><a ng-href="http://{{college.collegewebsite}}/?iframe=true&amp;width=100%&amp;height=100%"  rel="prettyPhoto[iframe]"><center>{{college.collegewebsite}}</center></a></h4>
      </li>
    </ul>



<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("area[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();

      $(".gallery:first a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({animation_speed:'normal',theme:'light_square'});
      $(".gallery:gt(0) a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({animation_speed:'normal', hideflash: true});

      });
  </script>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I think prettyphoto.js page occur some problem

Please give some help.

Comment: hi TZHX , you have any idea about this problem...